# Requests(url) is having after 5 iteration

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am attempting to run a webscraping algo on indeed using beautifulSoup and loop through the different pages. However, after 2-6 iterations, the requests.get(url) hangs and stops finding the next page. I have read that it might do something with the server being blocked but that would have blocked the original requests and it also says online that Indeed allows for web scraping. I have also heard that I should set a header but I am unsure how to do that. I am running on the latest version of safari and MacOs 12.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I came up with, thought this does not answer the question specifically, is by using a try expect statement and setting a timeout value to the request. Once the timeout value is reached, it enters the try except statement, sets a boolean value, and then continues the loop and try again. Code is inserted below.

```
while(i < 10):
    url = get_url('software intern', '', i)
    print("Parsing Page Number:" + str(i + 1))

    error = False

    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout = 10)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as err:
        error = True
    if error:
        print("Trying to connect to webpage again")
        continue

    i += 1
```

I am leaving the question as unanswered for now however as I still don't know the root cause of this issue and this solution is just a workaround.